# Making a simple get request when clicking a button in my react/redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, redux, react-redux

Sorry if this question is too broad, I can't seem to find an example that would fit right or make sense for what I am doing.

Basically one of my reducers is an object that contains the id, name and url each of my buttons in a list possesses. Whenever I click one of the buttons, I would like to make a get request to that url and return whatever data it contained in the form  of a list.
For now all the application does is print out the id, name and url of the button I pressed. How in the world can I make the get request to the url and display whatever is contains?

Here is my current code:

```
//example reducer of the button:
export default function(){
return [
{
    id: 0,
    name: button1,
    url: http://jsoncodeINeed.com/api
},

{
    id: 1,
    name: button2,
    url: http://otherJsoncodeINeed.com/api
}

   ];
}
//reducer that will take care of the action:
export default function(state=null, action){
switch(action.type){
    case 'MODULE_CLICKED':
        return action.payload;
        break;

}
return state;
}

 //actions
export const moduleClicked = (module) =>{
    return {
        type: "MODULE_CLICKED",
        payload: module
    }
}

//container for where I want to post the data in the button:
class ModuleLog extends Component{

    render(){
            return (
                <Panel
                    {this.props.module.name}{this.props.module.url}

                </Panel>
            );

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      module: state.moduleLog
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ModuleLog);

//container for the button group:
class ModuleButtons extends Component{

    createListItems(){
        return this.props.modules.map((module)=>{
            return (
                <ListGroupItemkey ={module.id}
                    onClick={()=>this.props.moduleClicked(module)}>{module.name}</ListGroupItem>
            );
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <ListGroup>
                {this.createListItems()}
            </ListGroup>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        modules: state.modules
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({moduleClicked: moduleClicked}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ModuleButtons);
```

My store is in the index.js file, where I simply display the components, which simply neatly display the containers.

Comment: You could use `redux-thunk` middleware to make asynchronous requests.

Comment: You will do the actual async call in an action. You can use thunk, or just use mapDispatchToProps (then you don't need another library). The basic idea is you pass whatever information you need for the call to the action creator, make the call, then pass the resulting data to your reducer to be placed on your states. Also one quick note - in your reducer you are returning action.payload instead of the state, which will override whatever you had in the state currently, so be careful of that.

Comment: @ajmajmajma I'm trying to do that with a url I put in manually, but currently I am struggling to connect that action with the rest of the application and I would have no idea how to do it from a url that is in another reducer.

Comment: It doesn't matter what reducer it's in? the reducers are there just to take the information from your action and place it on (return) the new "updated" state.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the [AsyncActions documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.md) in the redux page. Essentially, you want to make your request from an action that is fired when clicking the button. Upon receiving a response, you fire a second action (something like "SUCCESS_REQUEST") with the data received. The reducer would then update the store accordingly, which would update your UI.

Comment: I've tried reading redux page's documentation a few times as well as implementing some stuff along side, unfortunately I find it as confusing as it gets and nothing works from it when I try incorporating to my code :(

Comment: hoever, I should add that just that brief explanation of yours has already given me a bit of insight, so thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah I mean that one page does a really good job at going over the simplest case. If you post what you've tried maybe we can fix it?